# CKFinder real thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails, ckfinder

According to the docs its possible let generate real thumbnails...i want to use them on my website, instead of the original uploaded document. But i can not find generated thumbs on our server? Where should they supposed to reside?

Whether CKFinder should display real thumbnails for image files:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_thumbnails